# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List, how to handel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Error : ****The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[SlotIdentificationSystem.Models.User_Register_Event]'.**

---

**Model**

```
namespace SlotIdentificationSystem.Models
```

{

```
public class User_Register_Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }

    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public int EventTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual EventTable EventTable { get; set; }
    public int TermId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Term Term { get; set; }

}
```

}

---

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult ShowAllDetail(int UserTableId,int UserTableId2)     //bb1234  //bb4567
    {

        var data = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();
           //data eg [11,12,13.....]
        var data2 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId2).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

        //data2 eg [11,42,22.....]
      
        List<int> AllSlots = db.Slots.Select(x => x.Slot_Id).ToList();
              
        var result = AllSlots.Except(data.Union(data2)).ToList();
        return View(result);
    

          eg. //result=[72,19,41,44,...etc


    }
```

**CSHTML**

I have to show the **result** detail in cshtml, but I get the **defined** error. In debugging mode I am getting the result in controller what I want, but as soon as it move to view error comes..... need help in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You have the error since you really return list of slotIds. Try this:

```
var data = db.User_Register_Events
.Include(i=>i.EventTable)
.ThenInclude(i=>i.Slot)
.Where(x => x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId
 || x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId2).ToList();
  

var AllSlots = db.Slots.Select(x => x.Slot_Id).ToArray();
              
 var result = data.Where(item =>!AllSlots.Contains(item.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id))
.ToList();

 return View(result);
```

I only don't understand  why you use var AllSlots = db.Slots.Select(x => x.Slot_Id)?  You are selecting all slots and your result will be always null.
Try this:

```
//var data = db.User_Register_Events
//.Include(i=>i.EventTable)
//.ThenInclude(i=>i.Slot)
//.Where(x => x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId
// || x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId2).ToList();
//var AllSlots = db.Slots.Select(x => x.Slot_Id).ToArray();
              
 var data = db.User_Register_Events
.Where(x => x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId
 || x.UserTable.Id == UserTableId2).ToList();

 return View(data);
```

Comment: again having an error, i have updated with the model class as well, please have a look onpost again

Comment: I would like to see your view.